# Selenium WebDriver: junit Parameterized Tests - No runnable method

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, intellij-idea

I am very new to Selenium WebDriver and testing. I was wondering if you could help me with my code I am working on or point me to a place where I could better learn how to do this. Constructive criticism goes a long way.

I am trying to go to a webpage and check the page if any of the words, in a list/collection, are present. When I run the test, I get the error "No runnable methods." How can I fix this?

I have looked at multiple sites/tutorials and they have pointed me to using @RunWith(Parameterized.class). Any ideas on how to effectively do this?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public static class WordFilter {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { "word1" },
                { "word2" },
                { "word3" }
        });
    }

    private String words;

    public WordFilter(String words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Test
    public void filtering()
    {
        (Test Code)
    }
}
```

I have learned this with Intellij, Selenium Webdriver, junit, Maven.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Again, I am very new, so I am sorry for my limited knowledge.

Comment: Could you please post your stacktrace.

Comment: don't declare your class as static. Anyway, how do you run it?